# How to specify a minimum font size in a responsive web page

Tags: css, word-wrap

I've been trying to set a minimum font size for some text on my website. Previously this text used to shrink to an illegible size at mobile size so I set up a media query so that a specific font-size is set for smaller screen sizes.

@media (max-width: 760px) {

```
.tp-caption.medium-text {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    text-align:center !important;
    margin-top: 30px !important;
    }
```

}

The problem I'm having is how to get the text to wrap normerly. At the moment it doesn't wrap. When I add 'white-space: normal' to the styles it seems to wrap every word and I can't work out what other styles are working on this element to make it wrap in this strange way?

The website is here : www.alexch.net/ignition

Any advice would be appreicated

Many thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to wrap text, the css for this is;

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Your site should not be shrinking text, are you using % for font sizes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm basically customising a theme I bought. I think I probably need to ask the developer who built the theme as they should be able to tell me which other styles are overriding my attempts to specify that the text should wrap.

Comment: If you right click, and click inspect, using chrome dev tools, or firefox firebug, you will be able to see what is overriding.

Comment: Thanks! When I do that then I can see an element style :    

white-space: nowrap;

which I think is causing the problem. However when I specify 'white-space: normal;' in my ownstyles.css doc, every word seems to wrap onto a new line. Not sure if I should be using some other css rule to just get it to wrap before it goes off the edges of the screen?

Comment: Can you direct me to which section on your page/ site this problem is so i can fix for you :)

Comment: The website is live here : http://alexch.net/ignition/

It's the strapline under the main central logo that I'm having trouble with. I've put a 'white-space: normal' on it under a certain screen size but as you can see if you shrink the screen size down then every word seems to wrap. Not really what I want to happen - just to wrap before it gets to the edges of the screen! Thanks very much for offering to help with this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks Alex, ive just spent a few minutes investigating this. However i am struggling due to the slider keeps moving.

Can you tell me if you have any control over the markup, expecially the Javascript running this slider. It is being given a lot of inline styles which should not be there, thats why the text is shrinking depending on the size of the viewport.

Comment: Hi - Have just sent you an email (grabbed from your profile). Hope that's ok? See what you think and let me know! Thanks Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, no thats fine, Did you grab my email from my website? i am not sure which email is listed on my profile i dont think it is public and would not want you emailing the wrong address.

Comment: Hi - yes, went to your website and emailed from there